# Genesis 20:4 — Why does Abimelech stand for the whole nation?

Tags: genesis

> **Genesis 20:1-5** (translation mine)
>
> And Abraham journeyed from there to the land of Negeb, and dwelt between Kadesh and Shur, settling in Gerar.
>
> 2 Now of his wife Sarah Abraham had said, “She is my sister.” Therefore Abimelech, king of Gerar, sending *for her*, took Sarah *for his own wife*. 3 But God came to Abimelech in a dream by night, and said to him, “Behold, **you shall die** on account of the woman **you** have taken: for she is the wife of a husband *already*.” 4 Abimelech, therefore, did not approach her, but said, “Lord, would you really kill **a nation** that is innocent? 5 Did he not say to me, ‘She is my sister?’ She *herself* said *to me*, ‘He is my brother.’ In the sincerity of my heart and in the cleanness of my hands did I do this.”

### Question

Why did Abimelech conflate his own punishment with that of a whole nation?

Comment: _and if thou restore her not, know thou that thou shalt surely die, thou, and all that are thine._ (verse 7).

Comment: Hmm, does this simply mean we are looking at the summarized conversation, where God said this before verse 7?

Comment: related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/could-there-have-been-some-duplicity-on-the-part-of-the-israelites-in-achans-tr

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two related answers.

1. Abimelech, as king, viewed himself as the avatar for this country. He understood that if he were punished his whole nation would be punished. Which is why he says in verse 20:9 (speaking to Abraham)

> What have you done to us? And what is my sin to you that you should
>   bring upon me and **my kingdom** a great sin

2. Abimelech was seeking protection from G-d because of the innocence of his people. Abimelech invoked the righteousness of his nation who would surely suffer if the king and his household were destroyed as a defense to G-d. Destroying Abimelech wouldn't only hurt Abimelech but would harm the entire Philistine nation.